# The complement of an arc in $S^3$ is contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to S^3$ be an embedding, so that its image $X:=f([0,1])$ is an arc. How can we show that its complement $S^3-X$ is contractible? This is claimed in an answer of this question [Homology groups of the complement of a knot in $S^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476297/homology-groups-of-the-complement-of-a-knot-in-s3) that I asked before.

Answer (score 1):

By deforming the embedded path to a point, we can equivalently (up to homotopy) consider $S^3\setminus\{x\}$ for a point $x$. You can also consider $S^3$ to be the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^3$, i.e. $\Bbb R^3\cup\{\infty\}$. The homotopy type of $S^3\setminus\{x\}$ is the same as $\left(\Bbb R^3\cup\{\infty\}\right)\setminus\{\infty\}$, which is homotopy equivalent to $\Bbb R^3$ and thus contractible.

If that sounds over-complicated, all I'm really saying is that $S^n$ minus a point is contractible for any $n$ (and any point). You can also see this from the cell structure of $S^n$ using one zero cell and one $n$-cell. If you delete an interior point of the $n$-cell, you can deform $D^n$ to $S^{n-1}$, which is glued via the trivial map to the zero cell.

Comment: I can see that $S^n$ minus a point is contractible but I can't see why we can deform the embedded path in $S^3$ to a point. Do you mean that $S^3$ minus a point can be deformed to $S^3-X$?

Comment: You're right; my language there wasn't precise. But the intuition is that deleting a point is the same as deleting any other contractible subspace (up to homotopy equivalence). Since $S^3-\{x\}$ deformation retracts to $S^3-X$, the two spaces are homotopy equivalent. As Hatcher says, deformation retractions are sort of asymmetrical, but they imply homotopy equivalence which is an equivalence relation.

Comment: @pancini: Removing a point is not the same (up to homotopy equivalence) as removing any other contractible subspace. For example, removing $\{0\}$ from $[0, 1]$ gives a space homotopy equivalent to a point, but removing the contractible subspace $\{\frac{1}{2}\}$ from $[0, 1]$ gives a space homotopy equivalent to two points.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Interior point I mean

Comment: @pancini: What do you mean by interior point in the $S^3$ case? You said you can just defom the arc to a point and remove that instead without changing the homotopy type. What my example was trying to illustrate is that this argument is not true in general, so something more is needed.

Comment: Interior of a cell, I mean.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have said that so confidently because maybe theres some pathological counter example I'm overlooking. But for the sake of intuiting problems like this, certainly removing a point is the same as removing a disk, square, ball, path, etc.